# PHP | Should I Assign Shorthand if Statement to a varible

Tags: php, boolean, shorthand

I'm using a shorthand if statement to validate if a value is assigned to a variable, my question is should I assign the statement to a variable, because it's working if I assigned it or not.

statement not assigned to variable | working

```
!empty($name) ? $name : $name="";
```

statement assigned to variable | also working

```
$is_name = (!empty($name)) ? $name : $name="" ;
```

Both statements are working, but which one is correct or better to be used.

Comment: Don't use `empty()` to check, if a variable is set or not, use `isset()`. Else, it depends on what you want to do. If you just want to set the variable, if it hasn't been set before, your first statement is fine. It also makes more sense if you use `isset()` then.

Comment: The $name variable can be empty, so I used ` empty()` I will try it with `isset()` but still should I assign the whole statement to a variable, and lets say I want to echo the value of $name, should I write `echo $is_name` or `echo $name`

Comment: @KhorneHoly `empty()` is better (for text/integer inputs); it checks if it's both empty/set. `isset()` is best when using checkboxes/radios/select.

Comment: Great, so I should stick to empty in my situation, Thank you so much for the explanation ..

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'd never use `empty()` for checks with integers, because `empty(0) === true`, but 0 is a legit integer value.

Comment: @KhorneHoly You're talking integer; OP is obviously using a string; 2 different animals here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- just saying because you've said that `empty()` is better for text/integer inputs in your previous comment. For the OPs case it's totally fine.

Comment: again; `empty()` does both; checks if it's empty and set @KhorneHoly seems like we've a bit of a [communication breakdown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoqQnR8NOVI) here. Let's just agree to disagree then.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I agree with you. Kudos to your choice of music.

Comment: @KhorneHoly [Led Zeppelin I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Led_Zeppelin_(album)); gotta love it ;-) *Cheers* God bless Jimmy's eclectic rock 'n roll soul.

Answer (score 2):

In php 5.3+ you can use this:

```
$is_name = $name ?: "";
```

Note: In your case this is probably not the best idea, since it produces a warning, if $name is not set. Here I would still recommend the normal way

```
$is_name = isset($name) ? $name : "";
```

But the question is why to have a uninitialized variable anyway ?

If you just have the case that $name can be an empty string and you want to give it a default value in this case, the ?: operator is your fit.

```
$is_name = $name ?: "default value";
```

Comment: Yes exactly, the $name might be an empty string

Comment: @AhmadTahhan then you want to assign an empty string, if the string is empty ?

Comment: I will explain, I have page A and B, page A can send values through a form to a form in page B, so I want the values that's been inserted in form A to be shown in form B, that's why am checking if it has a value or not.

in the same time page B can be accessed independently and fill the form in it without the need of page A.

am sorry if made it complicated. I don't know if it's clear enough

Comment: @AhmadTahhan So you can access site B directly or from site A. And you get the values from page A from post/get variables (if they are set) ?

Comment: Yes exactly... That's what am trying to make, I can upload the pages on my server to show you what am trying to do if you want...

Comment: all statemntes are working fine and doing what I want, but I want to learn which one should be used

Comment: post a single statement of page b, where you get the post/get variable and set it as value. (Maybe you have to concate some code, so that we have a minimal example). I think this question is not quite what you are looking for =)

Comment: @AhmadTahhan What you probably want is nothing of all this but something like: <input id='name' value='<?php if isset($_POST['name']) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])?>' >

Comment: That worked too, I think am gonna stick to your solution 
`<input id='name' value='<?php if isset($_POST['name']) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])?>' >`

Thank you so much for the help and explanation

Answer (score 1):

this may be better. you don't need a extra ! operaiton and variable assignment.

```
  $is_name = empty($name) ? "" : $name;
```

or

```
  $is_name = isset($name) ? $name : "";  //recomended this one
```

Comment: A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.